# How do I prevent the image url from changing after scrapping using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to scrape the cover photo of Facebook using python selenium

it returns the url properly, however it gets changed and show a blurry one.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/events/851274783286508/?active_tab=about'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get(url)
cover_class = 'img.x1ey2m1c.x9f619.xds687c.x5yr21d.x10l6tqk.x17qophe.x13vifvy.xh8yej3'

img = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,cover_class)
print(img.get_attribute('src'))


requests.get(img.get_attribute('src'))


##################  THIS IS THE URL THAT SHOULD BE RETURNED  ################################



#perfect_src = https://scontent.fpsd2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/321296208_468127735500704_5967700403570897493_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=340051&_nc_eui2=AeFSxY7I0TKJvJRIx37yNz_jvkkF4L__0_G-SQXgv__T8a3A9q5B5t3jD54iDEhyayU7Wf-86Xko3e-lkPKiOl8v&_nc_ohc=kU48KdHWOFcAX_w-iW0&_nc_ht=scontent.fpsd2-1.fna&oh=00_AfCjDp7TSLV22b8WigiDlMedF9ONKuDXmW885vje3OAlMQ&oe=64573615





##################  THIS IS THE ACTUAL IMAGE URL I'M GETTING  ################################



#mehogcy_src = https://scontent.fpsd2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/321296208_468127735500704_5967700403570897493_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_fb50_s320x320&_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=340051&_nc_ohc=kU48KdHWOFcAX_w-iW0&_nc_ht=scontent.fpsd2-1.fna&oh=00_AfDSvqeVreyDGTVq4If0dBtyBA6H1PA0YV9CVaY3DLnupg&oe=64573615
```

How do I fix that?

I tried to scrape it using selenium as it shows in the code attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed below line:

```
img = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, cover_class)
```

To:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
img = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@data-imgperflogname='profileCoverPhoto']")))
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Result:**

```
https://scontent-fra5-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/321296208_468127735500704_5967700403570897493_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s960x960&_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=340051&_nc_ohc=kU48KdHWOFcAX8gWjDP&_nc_ht=scontent-fra5-2.xx&oh=00_AfA7hkoiTjbXx_ZMAKJEbYkLxLhlW-BsfxiMtFOBjLIIqA&oe=64593055

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I click on this URL printed on console, it opens as below:

[image]

Comment: Marvellous!!! 
Thank you So much, Shawn, it's working perfectly now.